# Difficulty in understanding the following problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the positive integers $n$ with exactly $12$ divisors
$1 = d_1 < d_2 < \cdots < d_{12} = n$ such that the divisor with index $d_4 - 1$ (that is,
$d_{d_4 − 1}$) is $(d_1 + d_2 + d_4)d_8$.

This is taken from the book on Number Theory by Titu Andreescu

Answer (score 1):

You're told that there is a divisor $d_k$ that is equal to $(1+d_2+d_4)d_8$, and that its index, $k$, is equal to $d_4-1$.  From $d_k=(1+d_2+d_4)d_8$ you know that $9\le k\le12$, because $d_k$ is obviously greater than $d_8$ and the problem says there are only $12$ divisors.  Using $k=d_4-1$, this becomes $10\le d_4\le13$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, it's clear to me now

Answer (score 0):

Your answer can be find in the same book : click [here](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=Mlt2O1rR9xIC&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=%22Find%20the%20positive%20integers%20n%20with%20exactly%2012%20divisors%22&source=bl&ots=OYpYEh32lH&sig=6HIdHDqTaRWkExebLvi5jOKAwNg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Oy57U63pLY7fkgWAm4GQDw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Find%20the%20positive%20integers%20n%20with%20exactly%2012%20divisors%22&f=false).

Comment: I don't need the solution, I need to understand what is being asked in the problem, which is also not clear from the solution.

Comment: Then tell us what you can't understand : you give us the exercise and we are supposed to know where is the problem ?